# Call StartDiscovery() through dbus without resetting the LE Scan Parameters

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez, whitelist

We are currently using the dbus API to connect with specific devices. We are using the classic method which is the subscription on the *PropertiesChanged*, but because of the tremendous number of bluetooth advertiser devices around, we decided to try to use the whitelist just like *hcitool* provides :

```
hcitool lewladd <MAC>
hcitool lescan --whitelist
```

We want to connect *BR/EDR* and *LE* devices but only *LE* devices that are in the whitelist.

I wrote a small C spike program that adds a device calling the following methods :

```
hci_le_add_white_list(...) // To add devices to the WL
hci_le_set_scan_parameters(...) // With "whitelist only" policy
```

However, as soon as I call the *StartDiscovery()* dbus method :

```
busctl call org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0 org.bluez.Adapter1 StartDiscovery
```

I see in the HCI events, that the "*LESetScanParameters*" is called again with an "Accept All" Policy (even if I already set it before to "Ignore not in whitelist". We are using bluez 5.50.

So my question is,

Is it possible to set the LE Scan parameters and then call the StartDiscovery() dbus call without resetting the former ?

NB: I know that it's possible to directly interact with the hci lib provided in bluez but it would require a complete refacto of the soft we are developping.

Thank you

EDIT : I forgot to mention that I want to use the whitelist because I want to filter by MAC addr and not by UUID.

Comment: You don't say what version of BlueZ you are using. Pattern came about 5.54 so you will need that version or newer.

Comment: You are right, in my bluez v5.50 this feature is not yet implemented...

Answer (score 1):

`hcitool` is a legacy tool/command. With BlueZ D-Bus the Adapter API contains a SetDiscoveryFilter() method, which allows you to install a corresponding filter.

Comment: I wanted to add that I want to filter by MAC addr and not by UUID, because too many devices of the same type advertise whit the same UUID and our callback is too much called

Comment: [Pattern](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt#n123) should allow this type of filter

Comment: Wonderful, I had no clue that MAC addrs were allowed in the filter through this field. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Unfortunately this feature is not yet implemented in v5.50

Comment: a classic case of "Have you tried the latest version?" :-)

Comment: https://www.linumiz.com/bluetooth-setdiscoveryfilter-for-filtered-scanning/ this can help